# React - Highcharts Chart will enlarge but wont shrink

Tags: reactjs, highcharts, flexbox, styled-components

I am working on a chart component in react that goes into a grid with responsive elements (panels that can open from the left depending on user choice- and should push the chart, shrinking it in size so it may fit).
The top parent layout is a grid with 2 columns, having a condition such as `${certainCondition} ? '0px 1fr' : '300px 1fr'.
The column that the graph is in has its own grid that breaks down into lines.

In my case i attempt to keep my chart in the same height while changing the width depending on the top parent grid column size (the 1fr size).
The issue i come across is that the chart will enlarge accordingly (stretching the bars to the appropriate width) - whenever i start with the panel open and then close it, or just start with a smaller window viewport size and then enlarge it.
But when i try and shrink the viewport size / open the side panel after the chart has rendered - it just wont budge, no matter what i did.
Any ideas on what the problem might be? Scoured the net and your forums for over a day but couldn't find any solution to it.

I tried to change every width property i can come across in the code / inspecting the page.
Nothing seemed to have any affect on the chart - seems like it receives a hard coded width number and rolls with it, only changing when it increments but never going down.

Thanks in advance and have a great day,
Gavriel.

Comment: It's difficult to figure out the problem without seeing the code. You might have already come across the following discussions, but let's check these links if they offer any solutions in your case:
https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/6427
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70110255/how-to-get-access-to-the-chart-from-highchartsreact-component-to-responsivegridl
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73672754/how-to-make-react-highcharts-height-responsive-on-resizing-via-react-grid-layout
If these don't resolve your issue, please provide a simplified code or a demo

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.